# Desktop environment missing

Tags: networking, drivers, login, tty

I had installed Radeon graphics drivers which messed up my system. It was unable to boot. So I went into the GRUB menu and uninstalled all the Radeon drivers, gave a nomodest login in the shell. After that I proceeded to reinstalling the ubuntu desktop environment which is where I got stuck. I am now only able to login into the tty shell and unable to even connect to ethernet or any USB port.

The only login I get is tty login which is unable to connect to the internet via ethernet. Running

```
 sudo ping 8.8.8.8.
 network not found
```

I can however access all my files and folder. What is the best way to restore the desktop environment? Or get ethernet access. I have tried enabling network via the grub menu. That doesnt turn on ethernet.

OS: 18.04.06 LTS

Comment: "*things went crazy*" is too vague to offer useful advice. Please edit your question to explain.

Comment: You've also not told us what OS/product/release you're using, so we're rather limited in what we can provide (esp. in regards specific advice for your *unstated* system).  You can view your *apt* logs to see what changes you made, and thus best reverse it; did you try that?